# Association Proxy SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

[This source](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#creation-of-new-values) details how to use association proxies to create views and objects with  values of an ORM object.

However, when I append an value that matches an existing object in the database (and said value is either unique or a primary key), it creates a conflicting object so I cannot commit.

So in my case is this only useful as a view, and I'll need to use ORM queries to retrieve the object to be appended.

Is this my only option or can I use merge (I may only be able to do this if it's a primary key and not a unique constraint), OR set up the constructor such that it will use an existing object in the database if it exists instead of creating a new object?

For example from the docs:

```
user.keywords.append('cheese inspector')

# Is translated by the association proxy into the operation:

user.kw.append(Keyword('cheese inspector'))
```

But I'd like to to be translated to something more like: (of course the query could fail).

```
keyword = session.query(Keyword).filter(Keyword.keyword == 'cheese inspector').one()
user.kw.append(keyword)
```

OR ideally

```
user.kw.append(Keyword('cheese inspector'))
session.merge() # retrieves identical object from the database, or keeps new one
session.commit() # success!
```

I suppose this may not even be a good idea, but it could be in certain use cases :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The example shown on the documentation page you link to is a `composition` type of relationship (in OOP terms) and as such represents the `owns` type of relationship rather then `uses` in terms of verbs. Therefore each `owner` would have its own copy of the same (in terms of value) keyword.

In fact, you can use exactly the suggestion from the documentation you link to in your question to create a custom `creator` method and hack it to reuse existing object for given key instead of just creating a new one. In this case the sample code of the `User` class and `creator` function will look like below:

```
def _keyword_find_or_create(kw):
    keyword = Keyword.query.filter_by(keyword=kw).first()
    if not(keyword):
        keyword = Keyword(keyword=kw)
        # if aufoflush=False used in the session, then uncomment below
        #session.add(keyword)
        #session.flush()
    return keyword

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(64))
    kw = relationship("Keyword", secondary=lambda: userkeywords_table)
    keywords = association_proxy('kw', 'keyword', 
            creator=_keyword_find_or_create, # @note: this is the 
            )
```

Comment: I believe that answer is showing the exact same thing as the docs, but the docs show you how to do it without overriding several methods on the class (I assume that's what the methods are doing in the class, I haven't checked).  My question was more about changing the behavior of that example to be more along the lines of what I want for my specific use case (not creating a new object every time I append, but using an existing one from the db if it can).

Comment: @DerekLitz: fair enough... will change the answer to base it on the documentation linked to in your question...

Comment: Yeah, that method looks like it will work, and is superior to just defining an `__init__` that would do the same thing, because that would make it so all objects would have to be instantiated that way, or add some complexity to the method. I noticed some mistakes though, and it is one of the problems I wasn't quite sure about.  What's the best way to obtain the session in order to do the query before insert?  Your code has a bug on the query, since it needs to be done with a session on the object, something like `session.query(Keyword).filter(Keyword.keyword=kw)`.

Comment: Bug? Really? First of all, you can use `object_session` (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.object_session) to get the session from the object and execute the query. But in case you use `declarative` extension (which is used in the example you reference to) it is common in simple scenarios (just one session) just to do `Base.query = session.query_property()`, and this is what I used in the sample code in the answer..

Comment: Very nice, I was not aware the ORM objects contained the session they were attached to as part of their state.  Since, it only makes sense to append a keyword to an object that is attached to a session (can't think of case where it wouldn't be), this will work handily. I like the idea of using that a little bit more then doing some monkey patching :)

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into the same problem. Mike Bayer, creator of SQLAlchemy, refered me to  the [“unique object” recipe](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/UniqueObject) but also showed me a variant that uses an event listener. The latter approach modifies the association proxy so that `UserKeyword.keyword` temporarily points to a plain string and only creates a new Keyword object if the keyword doesn't already exist.

```py
from sqlalchemy import event

# Same User and Keyword classes from documentation

class UserKeyword(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_keywords'

    # Columns
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True)
    keyword_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Keyword.id), primary_key=True)
    special_key = Column(String(50))

    # Bidirectional attribute/collection of 'user'/'user_keywords'
    user = relationship(
        User,
        backref=backref(
            'user_keywords',
            cascade='all, delete-orphan'
            )
        )

    # Reference to the 'Keyword' object
    keyword = relationship(Keyword)

    def __init__(self, keyword=None, user=None, special_key=None):
        self._keyword_keyword = keyword_keyword  # temporary, will turn into a
                                                 # Keyword when we attach to a 
                                                 # Session
        self.special_key = special_key

    @property
    def keyword_keyword(self):
        if self.keyword is not None:
            return self.keyword.keyword
        else:
            return self._keyword_keyword

    @event.listens_for(Session, "after_attach")
    def after_attach(session, instance):
        # when UserKeyword objects are attached to a Session, figure out what 
        # Keyword in the database it should point to, or create a new one
        if isinstance(instance, UserKeyword):
            with session.no_autoflush:
                keyword = session.query(Keyword).\
                    filter_by(keyword=instance._keyword_keyword).\
                    first()
                if keyword is None:
                    keyword = Keyword(keyword=instance._keyword_keyword)
                instance.keyword = keyword
```