# How to combine two model class in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, orm, sqlalchemy

I am new to ORM with SQLAlchemy and I only used to work with raw SQL. I have database tables, `Label`, `Position`, and `DataSet`like following:

[image]

And the corresponding python classes following:

```
class Label(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Label'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=true)


class Position(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Position'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=true)


class DataSet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DataSet'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    label_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Label.id'))
    position_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Position.id'))
    timestamp = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

But in my servie, I don't expose those `label_id` and `position_id`. So I made a new class `Data` to hold `label` and `position` as string.

```
# Not a full class to only show my concept
class Data:
    # data dictionary will have data 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # So it doesn't have ids. Label and Position as string
        keys = {'label', 'position', 'timestamp'}
        self.data = {k: kwargs[k] for k in keys}

    # An example of inserting data.
    # skipped detail and error handling to clarify
    def insert(self):
        session = Session()
        # get id of label and position
        # remember that it returns a tuple, not a single value
        self.data['label_id'] = session.query(Label.id).\
            filter(Label.name == self.data['label']).one_or_none()
        self.data['position_id'] = session.query(Position.id).\
            filter(Position.name == self.data['position']).one_or_none()
        # add new dataset
        self.data.pop('label')
        self.data.pop('position')
        new_data = DataSet(**self.data)
        session.add(new_data)
        session.commit()
```

But it looks somewhat ugly and I think there should be a simpler way to do it. Are there any way to combine these table classes using SQLAlchemy APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html) and [association proxies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) to make links from `DataSet` to `Label` and `Position` objects:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class DataSet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'DataSet'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    label_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Label.id'))
    label = relationship('Label')
    label_name = association_proxy('label', 'name')

    position_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Position.id'))
    position = relationship('Position')
    position_name = association_proxy('position', 'name')

    timestamp = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
```

After this you can access `Label` and `Position` objects linked to `DataSet` (and their names) through new attributes:

```
>>> d = session.query(DataSet).first()
>>> d.position
<Position object at 0x7f3021a9ed30>
>>> d.position_name
'position1'
```

Inserting `DataSet` objects is not so beautiful unfortunately. You can specify `creator` function for `association_proxy` which can get a name and create or retrieve a corresponding object (found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9674552/6682517)):

```
def _label_creator(name):
    session = Session()
    label = session.query(Label).filter_by(name=name).first()
    if not label:
        label = Label(name=name)
        session.add(label)
        session.commit()
    session.close()
    return label

label_name = association_proxy('label', 'name', creator=_label_creator)
```

After specifying `creator` functions for both proxies you can create new `DataSet` objects this way:

```
dataset = DataSet(
    label_name='label1',
    position_name='position2',
    timestamp=datetime.datetime.now()
)
```

Comment: I just have read about relationship but didn't know about association proxies. This will save my time. Thank you very much!