# Flask SQLAlchemy update only the link between 2 models

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

I develop an API with Flask, SQLAlchemy, Marshmallow in python 3.7.
I try to modify this object "item" that is related to many functions by a table link and vice versa.

```
{
"id": "0fef2a90-f468-4e8e-827d-3d1804cb3ad5",
"name": "item 1",
"functions": [],
}
```

I want to add an existing function in this item 1:

```
{
"id": "0fef2a90-f468-4e8e-827d-3d1804cb3ad5",
"name": "item 1",
"functions": [{
    "id": "35f56892-2154-4f11-8af5-6a13b1456fc4",
    "name": "function 1"
 }],
}
```

Here is my code with my models and schemas:

```
class ItemModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'item'

    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)

    functions = db.relationship('FunctionModel', secondary='link_item_function', uselist=True)


class FunctionModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'function'

    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, unique=True, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)

    items = db.relationship('ItemModel', secondary='link_item_function', uselist=True)


class LinkItemFunctionModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'link_item_function'

    function_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('function.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    item_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('item.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))

    link_item_function_pkey = db.PrimaryKeyConstraint(function_id, item_id)


from ma import ma

class FunctionSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):

    items = ma.Nested('ItemSchema', many=True, exclude=('functions',))
    class Meta:
        model = FunctionModel
        load_instance = True
        transient = True


class ItemSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):

    functions = ma.Nested('FunctionSchema', many=True, exclude=('items',))
    class Meta:
        model = ItemModel
        load_instance = True
```

When I do that, my API try to create the function, but I would like just create the link in the  table "link_item_function", not the function. And if the function does not exist, return an error. I looked everywhere but was unsuccessful.
Is there a good way to do this ?
I would like thing there are this solution directly in SQLAlchemy package.

Thank you in advance your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days and months of research, I found a solution with "associationproxy" through this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674166/association-proxy-sqlalchemy) and the [official documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) !